# Django how to get URL of object and pass it to the context to use in a template

Tags: django, django-urls

**The situation is the next:**

I have a template `blog.html` displaying blogs entries. ​

I also have a template `results.html` in which I'm displaying the blogs according to various queries.

For each blog displayed on the template `results.html` i want to create a link to the object URL on `blog.html`. So users can click on the link and they'll be redirected to the actual object URL. The URL of `blog.html` won't be always the same as I'm paginating each 3 blogs.

Note that my URLs look like this so i can't pass parameters `path('', views.blogListView.as_view(), name='blog'),`

In short, I'd like to get the URL of each object in the View and pass it to the context so i can use it as `<a href="">`

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have a page `blog.html` which lists the blogs and has pagination. Next you also have a `results.html` which is simply a filtered version of the above page. Next you want to link from this page to the `blog.html` for the respective blogs? Why don't you simply add a **`DetailView`** for each blog?...

Comment: Have you checked the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) utiity function? And you should still be able to pass arguments i think

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I don't want to a have a View per blog. All blogs are displayed directly in the template, therefore they are all in the same URL (except for the pagination).

Comment: How would the reverse function help me in this case? @name-andy